# Get full path of VBScript script file when WScript not available

Tags: vbscript

I'd like to get the full path to the script file I am executing.  A quick google search shows me that `WScript.ScriptFullName` will do the trick.  The problem is that I am executing this script outside of the Windows Script Host (I'm using [ScriptUnit](http://www.xt1.org/scriptunit)) and so if I try using that code I get the error:

> Variable is undefined: 'wscript'

How do I get the full path to the current script file if I can't use WScript?

Comment: ScriptUnit's GUI displays and it's XML log contains the full file spec(s) of the test code; so I don't understand your specific need to have an equivalent of WScript.ScriptFullName. AFAICS, ScriptUnit provides two COM objects - Assert and ScriptUnit; none of these exposes a 'get the current file spec' property or method, but such a feature could be added (if it is really worth the effort).

Comment: If this cannot be done, would you settle for the current working folder? `CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetAbsolutePathName(".")`

Answer (score 0):

Can't you shell out, start a small script with cscript and pass the value to the parentscript throug an environmentvariable ? Can't test this since i don't have or use ScriptUnit.
Obviously the following would not work sincve you don't have Wscript with you but has ScriptUnit a similar feature to read environmentvars ?

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "CScript.exe " & """" & ScriptName & """"  'this would set your environmentvar scriptpath
Set objProcessEnv = WshShell.Environment("Process") 
path = objProcessEnv("scriptpath")
```

Or start the script from a batch or other script, record the path in a text-file and read the contents of that file in your mainscript.